# ¿Como cargar datos de una base de datos de forma mas rápida en un navegador?

Tags: php, mysql

Mi inquietud es que quiero cargar mas de 100.000 datos que son coordenadas para visualizar municipios, pero no se como hacer la carga mas rapida y que no alente el navegador, la carga de los datos la realizó mediante de mysql a php,

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: vas a tener que mostrarnos como los cargas actualmente, el modelo de la base de datos, como es que se muestran tantos datos en una pagina.

Comment: ¿Cargar 100.000 datos de golpe?  ¿Y quien la use va a tener que buscar _algo_ entre esos 100.000 datos?  Yo aplicaría **filtros**, por ejemplo, por provincias, por municipios, por letras del alfabeto o algo... o un **buscador**. Pero... cargar 100.000 registros OMG, no le veo mucha utilidad a eso.

Comment: http://estafilococo.000webhostapp.com/Pol/caragaEnPhp.php esta es la pagina que carga el mapa pero tiene las coordenadas escritas directamente en php asi que no tiene conexion con mysql y lo que busco es hacer la carga mediante php para que mi pagina donde esta el mapa no este llena de coordenadas

Comment: Son 36.000 líneas, llámalo directamente a mysql y guárdate el dato en el servidor como archivo no?